# Efficient Way to Replace Custom Strings with Numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I currently have a cell array in MATLAB that contains a list of serial numbers. Serial numbers are basically strings without any particular structure - so that my cell array is something like:

> serial_numbers  = {'serial1';  'serial1';  's2';  'serial31010'}

Given that each unique string within serial_numbers corresponds to a different item, I would like to assign an integer value to each of them... so I can change

> serial_numbers  = {'serial1';  'serial1';  's2';  'serial31010'}

into

```
new_serial_numbers = [1;1;2;3]
```

Right now, I do this by using the unique and strcmp functions as follows

```
unique_serial_numbers = unique(serial_numbers);
new_serial_numbers = nan(size(serial_numbers));

for i = 1:length(unique_serial_numbers)
   new_serial_numbers(strcmp(serial_numbers,unique_serial_numbers(i))) = i;
end
```

Of course this is really slow for large  I would like to convert each serial into an integer value. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: does your cell array contain _only_ numbers or also letters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track. After defining:

```
serial_numbers = {'serial1'; 'serial1'; 's2'; 'serial31010'}
```

This seems to be simple:

```
[~,~,new_serial_numbers ] = unique(serial_numbers,'stable')
```

will give:

```
new_serial_numbers =   1   1   2   3
```

Don't know about the performance of the 'unique' function

Comment: +1 I've done this a bunch in production code and can confirm the unique() performance is about as good as you can expect for this. You can also grab the first two outputs of `unique` and now you have a symbol table that you can use to encode newly encountered strings using `ismember` and some logic to expand the table.